# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un jFrame a otro, pero ambos estando abiertos?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jtable

Tengo duda de *cómo pasar información de un formulario a otro* pero ambos estando abiertos.

Específicamente quisiera saber como hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo un formulario con un botón de búsqueda, al presionarlo se abre otro *form* y ahora tengo los dos abiertos, este *form* contiene una tabla con un modelo cargado y dos botones: *cancelar y seleccionar*.
Hasta ahí todo está correcto, pero quisiera saber cómo pasar toda la información al otro formulario con el botón de búsqueda que ya está abierto.
Muchas gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: y el código? es más fácil ayudarte si nos anexas código.

Comment: Revisa este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580000/transfer-data-from-one-jframe-to-another-jframe-using-static-class-or-this-refer seguro te es de ayuda. la alternativa mas "simple" es pasar una referencia entre ventanas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es muy facil , debes crear variables especificas para eso, segun lo que quieras guardar por un tipo u otra, y haz que cada vez que pase ventana(al evento del boton) antes de pasar alamacene los daos en variables que bien podrian ser static para cuando hagas la instacia de la otra ventana lo peudas recuperar facilemente

Comment: Si eso ya lo hago, capturo los datos en una variable estatica y todo, pero en lo que estoy trabado es en que.. como le digo al formulario que ya estaba abierto, que agarre el dato cuando le de al seleccionar del formulario donde realizo la busqueda...
el dato lo lleno en una variable estatica en una clase al darle al boton de seleccionar

Answer (score 1):

Yo intente tal como dice en la respuesta pero la clave esta al momento de crear los formularios intenta con JDialogs no trabajes con jForms ahí va ser mucho mas fácil poder trabajar con la informacion que desees abiertas las dos ventanas simultáneamente.

JdialogUNO

Este es mi Formulario en donde quiero traer la informacion desde una tabla sin que esta se baya a serrar.

```
     public void  buscarCliente(String id)
{
    prDP.setIdCliente(id);
    prDP.ListarClientes(1);
    CargarDatos(); 
}


 /**
 * cargar Datos desde la tabla seleccionado
 * @return 
 */
public void CargarDatos()
{ 
    txtID.setText(prDP.getIdCliente());
    txtdni.setText(prDP.getDni());
    txtnombres.setText(prDP.getNombres());
    txtdir.setText(prDP.getDir());
        
}
```

El boton que se va al formulario en donde esta mi tabla con la informacion

```
 private void btnbuscarInformacionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
                                                
FormDos fr2=new FormDos(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
fr2.setVisible(true);
    if (!fr2.id.isEmpty()) {
        buscarCliente(fr2.id);
    }
}
```

JDialogDOS

Aqui tengo una variable de tipo Public id para poder capturar el id de mi tabla

```
public String id="";
```

Ahora en mi tabla Events-mouse-mousepresed para trabajar con doble click capturo el id de la informacion que necesito esta ventana se cierra, o puedes quitar el dispose() para que no se cierre como tu quieras y automáticamente la informacion ya estará en el formulario Uno

```
 private void tabladatosMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
Point p = evt.getPoint();
    int f = tabladatos.rowAtPoint(p);
     if(evt.getClickCount()==2)
    {  
       id=String.valueOf(tabladatos.getModel().getValueAt(f,0)); 
       this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Espero haya podido haberme echo entender.